# How to install clang-14 on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: clang, 23.10

How to install `clang-14` on Ubuntu 23.10 ?

The command `apt list --all-versions` shows only version 16.
I need the older version due to a project requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `clang-14` is available for Ubuntu 23.10 from the [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/clang-14) ... You'll need to add/enable the universe branch first with for example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

... then, update your repositories cache with:

```
sudo apt update
```

... then, simply install it like so:

```
sudo apt install clang-14
```